# How to change view using pyQt and appScheduler?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm new in python. I'm writing desktop application which should remind user each x minutes about exercises. When counter reach time application should change view to view with video.

In application I'm using Python 3.7, [appScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [event-notifier](https://pypi.org/project/event-notifier/),  [pyQt 5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) with [designer](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download).

Whole application uses one window. I use `QStackedWidget` to change views between.

To achieve my goal I run `appScheduler` in my main controller action. After x time it triggers action which should change the view.

```py
  EventDispatcher().getDispatcher().raise_event("onSettingsUpdate", view=view)
```

Listener:

```py
  # ...
  scheduler.getScheduler().add_job(self.changeView, 'interval', [view], minutes=time, id="exercise_block_scn_3", replace_existing=True, )
  # ...

def changeView(self, view):
  view.page_main.setCurrentWidget(view.view_video)
```

When I try to run application I get errors:

> ```
> 'job_state': pickle.dumps(job.__getstate__(), self.pickle_protocol)
> ```
>
> TypeError: cannot pickle 'QWidget' object

I searched StackOverflow to understand this problem. I found, that when I try to set view as a function parameter it uses pointer object. AppScheduler uses other thread than the main application and it creates problem. AppScheduler doesn't have access to memory from the first threat.

I'm looking for nice solution for this problem.
One the solution is to override view object and change it to stop using pointers.
I don't think that's good workaround when I generate files using desinger.

Do you have ideas how to solve it in nice way?

For better picture here is a link to git repo:
https://github.com/TheGeniesis/PAK

PR with last changes where I tried to solve described problem
https://github.com/TheGeniesis/PAK/pull/23/files

Related changes are here:

https://github.com/TheGeniesis/PAK/pull/23/files#diff-3208ab0a9716ff23ea9f343d3cab88db9831089e8316bd44568a9c6557667c9fR42

https://github.com/TheGeniesis/PAK/pull/23/files#diff-f98587bb5b4b6eca87e710b9fb8487a58212feba106eb30dc04456f26da27504R45

EDIT:

here is the simplest example:

MainView.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 30, 441, 471))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.view_main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.view_main.setObjectName("view_main")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.view_main)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 67, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.view_main)
        self.view_wideo = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.view_wideo.setObjectName("view_wideo")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.view_wideo)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 110, 67, 17))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.view_wideo)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Main"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Video"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from scheduler import Foo

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar(ui)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

scheduler.py:

```
from MainView import Ui_MainWindow
from apscheduler.schedulers.qt import QtScheduler

scheduler = QtScheduler({
    'apscheduler.jobstores.default': {
        'type': 'sqlalchemy',
        'url': 'sqlite:///jobs.sqlite'
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.default': {
        'class': 'apscheduler.executors.pool:ThreadPoolExecutor',
        'max_workers': '20'
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.processpool': {
        'type': 'processpool',
        'max_workers': '5'
    },
    'apscheduler.job_defaults.coalesce': 'false',
    'apscheduler.job_defaults.max_instances': '3',
    'apscheduler.timezone': 'UTC',
})
scheduler.start()

def changeView(view: Ui_MainWindow):
    print("run")
    view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(view.view_wideo)

class Foo:
    def bar(self, view):
        time = 0.1
        print("asdasd")
        scheduler.add_job(changeView, 'interval', [view], seconds=time, id="exercise_block_scn_1", replace_existing=True, )
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], not external links

Comment: As mentioned by eyllanesc, you should try to reproduce your problem with a standalone smaller example; your application is too advanced to answer to your question by looking at its repository. However, from the error you got, my guess is that someone (the app scheduler ?) is trying to dump the `ExerciseTimeListener` instance which now contains a QObject `__view` of type `Ui_MainWindow`. Try to implement the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`methods used by the pickelisation process. In these methods, you should return (resp recover from) a internal state of your class as a tuple or dict.

Comment: @eyllanesc I added the simplest example which reproducing problem.

Comment: @Frodon I created simpler app to reproduce the problem. As far I understand I should implement `__getState__` and `__setState__` in `Ui_MainWindow`. The problem is that designer generates this file and even I change something it will be overridden.

Comment: Actually you simple example is not really similar to your case: `changeView` is now a function, not a class method anymore. You should keep your class `ExerciseTimeListener` with the `changeView` method and add the `__getState__` and `__setState__` to this class. These methods should not deal with the `Ui_MainWindow`instance as it is not picklable. I think is it not a problem since this object `view` is given as a parameter of `changeView`, it is not part of the internal state of the class.

Comment: @Frodon Yes, in simple example I did this small mistake. however, when I have method outside and inside object Foo it returns the same error. In original code I tried two ways: 1. don't store state of view as a class param and use it as a normal variable 2. Store view (__view) as a class param. In both cases I had the same error. About `__getstate__` I found examples where pickled class is used outside (Create new instance of class and then use it). In my case I will need to use it inside (Pickle `ExerciseTimeListener` and self use). Which confuses me. Or I just misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class does not have any internal state, and if this is the class that causes the problem, can you try this:

```py
class ExerciseTimeListener:
    __view: Ui_MainWindow

    def changeView(self, view):
        view.page_main.setCurrentWidget(view.view_video)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict()

    def __getstate__(self, state):
        pass
```

Edit :
The problem is the `QObject` given as argument of your function. So the idea is to change that argument, but to still be able to retrieve the view.

You could give a view name as a string, and in the body function call a `getView(view_name)` to retrieve this view. The relationship between the name and the view can be done with a global dict, when instantiating the `Foo` class.

Consider registering the view from the caller script `MainView.py`:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from scheduler import Foo
    from scheduler import viewDict

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    # Register the view
    viewDict[ui.objectName()] = ui

    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar(ui)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this would be `scheduler.py`:

```py
viewDict = {}

def getView(view_name):
    return viewDict.get(view_name)

def changeView(view_name: str):
    print("run")
    view = getView(view_name)
    # Check if the requested view is registered
    if view:
        view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(view.view_wideo)
    else:
        print("No view called {}".format(view_name))

class Foo:
    def bar(self, view):
        time = 0.1
        print("asdasd")
        scheduler.add_job(changeView, 'interval', [view.objectName()], seconds=time, id="exercise_block_scn_1", replace_existing=True, )
```

Comment: I tried to use `view` set, get state as you wrote and I tried to use + `__view` in both cases the problem still exists.

Comment: Well, according to the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#adding-jobs), `Any arguments to the callable must be serializable`, which is clearly not the case for the view object.

Comment: since no one answered my question.
Do you have any ideas on how I can solve my problem?

Comment: I edited my answer and tried to provide a solution.